# Is the Runnable started by the AsyncContext in a Servlet thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, asynchronous

I'm almost sure, but it is better to get this clarified: If a `Runnable` is started in an `AsyncContext` of a servlet request, is the code within the run method thread-safe? I assume it is. Because there is a new `Runnable` per thread, isn't it? Can anybody clarify this question?

Comment: If it consumes something from shared memory e.g. a `List` available for all threads, then it may not be thread safe.

Comment: @Luiggi: Yes, you are right, I assumed no shared resources being used.

Comment: @Sotirios: You start the AsyncContext with a Runnable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Java code, unless explicitly written like so, is inherently thread safe. `AsyncContext` exposes a `start(Runnable)` method that accepts a `Runnable` value. If you have a `Runnable` instance and pass it as an argument to `start(..)` and then re-use it in some other thread, its thread-safety might be compromised.

What's more, if your `Runnable` was initialized with some state that is shared with other parts of your app, its thread-safety will again be uncertain.

It's all about how you manage it.

Comment: You are completely right. My question was motivated by the fact that servlets are always reused across threads whereas the Runnable is created per request (if you do not explicitly decide to reuse it). But, yes, if I have a shared state across all these Runnables, I get the same issues as with the servlet.